# 1.9 - Unable to login to admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, session, administration

I am just new in magento. I have installed magento on my localhost. After installing I have tried to login as admin, But I can't be able to login. I have tried in different browsers, But all browsers are redirecting to the login page itself. I have tried the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159420/magento-admin-panel-not-login-using-chrome-but-working-fine-in-firefox) question. But it was producing error.

Please any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Better to set up a virtual host in your local environment than run under localhost.

Comment: @JonathanHussey do you have any Idea why this is not logging in.

Comment: Magento has logic built in to not log you in if running under localhost.  Don't ask me why it was added in, but you really need to be running under a proper domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this answer to help those who are facing the same problem.

As JonathanHussey suggested in the comment. I have created a virtual host in my system. And reinstalled the Magento. After completion of installation, when I tried to login everything is working fine.

I think this was the best solution for this problem, rather than editing the Magento core.